# WrapPanel in Silverlight, binding CLR Objects

Tags: silverlight-2.0, wrappanel

Can anybody please help me? I need to bind CLR Objects to a WrapPanel in SILVERLIGHT. What should be displayed in the end is a couple of Image Thumbnails with their description (Text). I know how to do it with a ListBox, but I need it to be a WrapPanel, so my Thumbs will be displayed horizontally and break into a new raw... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you still want your control to be a ListBox, but you set the ItemsPanel of the ListBox to be a WrapPanel such as

```
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

It will then display the items horizontally and wrap at the end of the line.

Comment: Thanx for that, but I'm not really sure how to use this. I mean, my XAML code doesn't look anything like this... not even close. <ItemsPanelTemplate> causes errors.

Comment: Sorry, you will need to download the Silverlight toolkit also as the WrapPanel is not part of the standard Silverlight framework.

www.codeplex.com/Silverlight

you XAML would then look like

<ListBox>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>

to create a list box.

Comment: Yeah, I sure did install the toolkit. According to the code you send me, everything looks ok, but as soon as I try to bind the content, nothing visible happens. I also tried to copy/paste my item code into the WrapPanel, but "ItemTemplate" and "ItemSource" are not recognized and cause errors. Everything looks perfect in a ListBox, but I still need it in a WrapPanel (Horizontal first).
Thanx for your help though...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to replace the StackPanel INSIDE the ListBox with the WrapPanel. Very simple... you just have to know it!